# How to model an empty dictionary in pydantic

Tags: python, pydantic

I'm working with a request of a remote webhook where the data I want to validate is either there, or an empty dictionary. I would like it to run through the model validator if it's there but also not choke if it's an empty dictionary.

input 1:

```
{
   "something": {}
}
```

input 2:

```
{
    "something": {
        "name": "George",
    }
}
```

input 3:

```
{
    "something": {
        "invalid": true
    }
}
```

```py
class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str

class WebhookRequest(BaseModel):
    something: Union[Person, Literal[{}]]  # invalid literal
```

How would I model something like this in Pydantic such that inputs 1 and 2 succeed while input 3 fails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `extra = "forbid"` option to disallow extra fields and use an empty model to represent an empty dictionary.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Empty(BaseModel):
    ...

    class Config:
        extra = "forbid"


class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str

    class Config:
        extra = "forbid"


class WebhookRequest(BaseModel):
    something: Person | Empty

    class Config:
        extra = "forbid"
```